# Stackview behaving unexpectedly with hidden button

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

I am using the xcode 7.3.1 interface builder and am putting an uilabel and an uibutton next to each other inside a stackview.

[image: View]

UIabel left, UIButton right

[image: BeforeStacked]

Once I embed them into the stackview the uilabel expands to fill the entire stackview and the button is not visible at all.

The  UILabel expands to fill the entire stack view.

[image: afterStack]

As part of troubleshooting, I attempted to make the UILabel narrower by adding a width constraint, once added I get an error saying the width conflicts with UILable.leading align to: Superview and UILable.trailing align to: Superview. I did not set either of these constraints and have not had this issue with other stackviews.

[image: Stack Identity][image: Stack Attributes]

Comment: That is how Stack view works. Find a tutorial. There is an excellent one on ray wenderlich.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thank you for the feedback. Perhaps my question is not clear. In a one item stack view or if the item was the only thing in a row of a stackview I would expected it's leading and following edges to align to the view. However, in this instance there are two items in the view and one of them is being set to align leading and trailing to the view, overrunning the second item.

Comment: it would be much clearer if you had a screenshot or code to show us. But still, if you are adding or looking at constraints inside a Stack view then you have fundamentally misunderstood what Stack views are for.

Comment: what have you set the properties of the stack view to? Again, show a screenshot.

Comment: @Fogmeister with no constraints on the subviews at all once I embed the UILabel and the UIButton into a stackview the UILabel expands to fill the stackview and the UIButton's width becomes 0. Added screenshot of stackview attributes and identity panels.

Comment: Seriously. Find a tutorial. See the bit that says "Alignment" and it is set to "fill". A tutorial will show you what that means. Hint: it is relevant here. You will also find out what all the other settings mean and learn about nesting stack views.

Comment: Thanks, I have nested stack views in other parts of this app and this is the only one giving me trouble. I will play around more with these settings.

Comment: we still have no idea what your view looks like or what you want it to look like. It is very hard to determine what something looks like from a few brief sentences. Add screenshots and details to your question. As humans we are much better at understanding what something looks like by just looking at it.

Comment: @Fogmeister I added some images to the question. After looking at a tutorial I saw that "Alignment" was used to change the position of where the elements are in the view. But, the fill option simply placed the elements side-by-side which is what I want. Please see the edits to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the ultimate cause of this issue.

The problem is that the "View info" button is set to "Hidden". This is because the button does not appear unless specific circumstances are met. Because the button is set to "Hidden" the stack view auto-adjusts constraints so that it does not display.

The solution was to uncheck "Hidden" and to arrange everything the way I want and then to recheck "Hidden" for the button.

While I was able to create new labels and buttons and put them into a stack view, they quickly fell to the same issue once I marked the button as "Hidden" so the answers below did help me discover the cause.

Answer (score 2):

To get a view that looks like your first image do the following.

First delete the views you have (well add them later)

Now add a stack view and add constraints to lay it out on the screen. Top, bottom, leading, trailing.

Now set these properties.

- Axis : horizontal
- Spacing : 16
- alignment : fill
- distribution : fill
- layout margins : custom (top: 16, bottom: 16, left: 16, right: 16)

Now add your label and button to it. Set the label text and the button text.

Now add a width constraint (only width nothing else) to the button to make it keep the width you want.

That should sort it. If it doesn't it's because I still don't really know what layout you're actually trying to achieve.

Play around with the numbers to try to get it right. Just don't add any additional constraints. You don't need any.

If you add a screenshot showing what you want your view to look like (including the super view etc) it will be much easier to help. You are currently hiding a lot of information that makes it very hard to help.

Comment: This works with brand new label and button, but if I try to use my already existing label and button (even with no constraints) it has the same issue as stated before. The goal I have is to have the label and button horizontally beside each other in the stack view. I would prefer to use the existing objects because there is a lot of code already tied to them. I will update with the entire view.

Comment: @CSjunkie what do you mean by "a lot of code tied to them"? These are views. They are rectangles. There is no code in the interface builder.

Comment: I will update with the rest of the view, there are buttons that interact with web services that change the text and visibility of them. I can re-direct this functionality to the new buttons but would prefer not to.

Comment: @CSjunkie it is literally a case of doing a single ctrl drag to do that. Either way. The way that works is infinitely better than the way that doesn't work regardless of how much longer it takes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Remove all constraints
- Position the stack where you want it
- Use horizontal and vertical alignment (using current canvas values)
- Apply width and height constraints

Comment: With Stack views you should not be adding any constraints. That's the point of using stack views.

Comment: @Fogmeister that's not always the case. You may want something manually positioned inside.

Comment: @courtsimas no, really no. If you want it positioned in a different way then you can nest stack views or you don’t use a stack view. When you add manual constraints it conflicts with the constraints added by the stack view and can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to do alignment = fill and distribution to fill proportionally

Comment: It sounds like your situation is not the same as this question. If you have posted a question please link it here and I will see if I can help.